# securing internal rest api traffic

Tags: security, docker, microservices

There is a lot of google hits out there but I can't find a satisfactory answer. We are currently adopting the micro-services architecture. My current concern is with internal rest API calls. I've read plenty that says even though the calls are internal we should still encrypt the traffic. Okay that's great, but what is the best approach. I need to work out if I can ignore the issue for now and use http and then retrofit https later.

My current thoughts:

1. Use http, run micro-services as docker containers and let docker encrypt the traffic using for example a network overlay. This seems the easiest option to me.
2. Use a self signed certificate deployed with each docker container. However in general my services communicate via IP addresses and do not use hostnames since some services need to be client load balanced if required. So how do you create a self signed certificate that java will be happy with when doing https calls between services?

I'm sure there is a better way? Any pointers would be appreciated.